# AJAX call inside Ember.RSVP.Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, rsvp.js

I have the following common code to invoke AJAX requests. My question is if the "return" keyword is necessary for the $.ajax (since doing $.ajax would anyways return a promise) OR if it is for some other purpose ?

```
doXhr: function(postData, requestUrl){  
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {        
        return $.ajax({ //Is the "return" required on this line ?
            url: requestUrl,

        })
        .done(function(response, status, xhrObject) {         
          resolve(response);
        })
        .fail(function(xhrObject, status, error){           
            reject(errorObj);
        });
    })  
    return promise;
},
```

Comment: This is the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). *Dont do this*. You can just do `const promise = Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax({url: requestUrl}))`

Answer (score 2):

just like other promise libraries (Native, Bluebird, etc), the `resolve`, `reject` functions are actually callbacks, so there is no need for a return inside the `new Promise`. (If you never call resolve or reject though, your promise will be pending forever).

The only return that is needed in the return of the `RSVP.Promise` like what you have at the bottom -- though only if you are `await`ing or `then`ing `doXhr`

Also, neat side-tip:

With the the more recent ember, you can just do:

```
import { Promise } from 'rsvp';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // stuff
});
```

### Edit

for how the function body of the promise get's executed, you'll need to look at the constructor of the Promise: 
https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/lib/rsvp/promise.js#L143

the `resolver` function (the function you define when making a new promise) is passed to here https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/lib/rsvp/-internal.js#L231  and then evaluated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot...Just one more question; Whenever this line is encountered,  var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise .....the code inside the constructor will automatically get invoked...meaning we do not have no invoke the constructor function explicitly...How does that work ?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, I think that's just a javascript weirdness around how classes are implemented (as functions instead of first _class_ citizens (there are trade-offs to this approach)). The same behavior happens when you do `Array(1, 2)` or `new Array(1, 2)`

Comment: Is the above you stated with reference to ES5 or ES6 standard ? Actually I was just trying to understand how does new Ember.RSVP.Promise() get executed immediately...meaning without any explicit call to it like callMyConstructorFunction()

Comment: ah ok. the constructor of the promise executes the function you pass to it :)

Comment: testndtv, I've updated my answer with some details.

and re: ES5 vs ES6, I don't actually remember. It's been a while since I've written vanilla ES5, buuuut, Chrome's console natively supports arrow functions.